# If I want to push to a remote repo that has commits ahead, git erases the local changes

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, git-merge, rebase

I use IntelliJ, and if I do some local changes and then push to the remote repo, sometimes appears this:

[image]

If I do "Merge" or "Rebase" it simply erases my local changes. I thought it would show(and I'd liked to have) a window where I could choose which files to choose between the local and the remote repo, so that I can choose which file to have. BUT it actually doesn't show anything and just erases everything to have the remote repo files. Why? How to "fix" this?

Obviously, if (before pushing) I update the project pulling remote repo, it says I need to merge. And if I do that, again, it erases everything, so I need to revert the changes to take my local files back.

UPDATE:
If I comment an "@Override" line, it shows the window where I can "Accept their" and "Accept yours"... why?? If I do other things like adding comments or adding a println, it, again, erases my changes. But if I comment the "@Override" line, it "works".

Comment: What about [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#update-your-working-copy-if-push-is-rejected). Step-by-step introductions from Jetbrains.

Comment: And what do you mean with „erase local changes“? Have you changes that aren’t yet committed?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen no, I committed them all

Comment: *GIt* does not do this at all. IntelliJ might do this (I don't know, I don't use IntelliJ). If you want to control Git directly, don't hide behind an IDE; if you like the IDE except for this one behavior, that's fine, but it's not Git's fault that the IDE behaves like this.

Comment: I fixed by manually deleting the folder and pasting the updated folder, then committed and pushed lol.

Comment: If you do "Merge" or "Rebase" and you have some commits that are conflicting with remote commits, then IDE should prompt you to resolve such conflicts

If you have some changes that are not commited, then they are not deleted, but they should be placed in shelf  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html